# Is it possible to translate Knowledge article content details and related links part?

Tags: knowledge, translation, articles

I have created a Knowledge article with translations, and it works fine.
The issue is that I have 2 subtitles which is not translated. This is the **Details** and **Related** **links** subtitles.

I'm using this article in a LWC component.

Is it possible to apply translations to these items as well?

[image: details and related link part]